# How to Elementor Form Check field to be required

Tags: forms, elementor

I am using elementor form in which I am using check field is there any way to make that field required
I can,t use the radio button Because I want the use to select more then one field but atleast should be one field is selected.
is there any jquery I can use for that

If anyone can help me with the code
which make that check field required.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t39Fh.png)